# Windows FTP Client : Limit data port range

Tags: windows, networking, ftp

There is a tool in my company that uses the native Windows FTP client (ftp.exe).
This FTP client sometimes uses a port for data connection which is recognized by the firewall as peer-to-peer by the application control layer.

I would like to know if I have a way to limit the port range used by the FTP client in the registry or somewhere else.

Thank you for your help.

Alexandre

Comment: No, there's no way.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the short answer. I did noy find any clear answer to this issue. Not sure why 2 people voted down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

Cannot you use a different Windows command-line FTP client and passive mode? It would solve all the problems with firewall.

For example [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/)? There's even a [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I am currently replacing the ftp scripts with Powershell + WinSCP Automation but I am searching a workaround fof this issue in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

**See update below**

Only with Active FTP can the client decide on which ports to use, using the `PORT` command:

```
...
PORT 192,168,0,2,7,123
200 PORT command successful
LIST
...
```

The server is instructed to connect to 192.168.0.2 at port *7*256 + 123 = 1915*. The two numbers at the end are the higher and lower 8 bit of the 16 bit port number.

However, with Active FTP the server will connect to the client. This is not suitable for clients behind firewalls or NAT routers. With Passive FTP, it’s the opposite: the client opens additional connections to the server. Thus, Passive FTP is now the de-facto standard. But with Passive FTP, the client *cannot* decide on which port to use:

```
...
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,3,7,123).
LIST
...
```

Now, the client has to initiate to connection to the IP address and port indicated in the server reply (`227 Entering ...`). While still problematic with firewalls because it’s not a “known” port, it is fully supported on NAT routers without FTP helpers.

**tl;dr**: Only with Active FTP. Active FTP won’t work though.

#### Update

Now that it’s clear that this question is about `ftp.exe`, the explanation above is mostly irrelevant because `ftp.exe` only supports Active FTP. However, the behavior of `ftp.exe` cannot be controlled/modified. A different FTP client is required.

Most clients *do not* support configuration or control of the data port range. Excerpt from the [WinSCP manual](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes):

> As WinSCP does not allow configuring a range of the ports it uses for data connections, all ports in Windows dynamic port range 49152 - 655354) have to be opened.

You might want to reconsider your entire approach to transferring files. FTP is simply outdated. Using a single-port protocol (SFTP, HTTP, ...) to transfer the file might be a better way.

Comment: Yes. I am talking about ftp.exe. No passive mode with this client

Comment: I see. This information needs to be in the question. Please also explain how it is used, if possible. Because if you want to change its behavior, you'll need a different, *proper* client.